Issue with Inter-Cluster Communication Between Apps in Different Kind Clusters
I have app1 and app2. The whole purpose of what I'm doing is to have one Go server (app1) deployed in one cluster which returns the IP of the caller and a Go server (app2) in another cluster that will call app1 to get its egress IP.
I'm very new to Kubernetes and so far I'm only running app1 and app2 locally in kind.
When I'm running any of the two servers in a cluster and calling them from my machine it works, but trying to make app2 call app1 where they are running in different clusters and in different namespaces fails (it neither works if they are in the same or different namespaces).
I call app2 from my machine with:
curl http://localhost:30002/ip
And it gives the response:
Get "http://app1.example.com:30001/ip": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:30001: connect: connection refused
App2 calls app1 with the code:
    resp, err := http.Get("http://app1.example.com:30001/ip")

Again, it works as long as I call app1 directly with:
curl http://app1.example.com:30001/ip
So I don't understand why app2 cannot call it.
I'm using an ingress with the dummy domain name app1.example.com.
I'm unsure if I should specify the port 30001 here. I'm doing it because if I don't, I get the exact same error message but where it uses port 80 as the default, so:
Get "http://app1.example.com/ip": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
Which I assume is because I have not specified port 80 to be used anywhere.
If I call app1 directly from outside the cluster I have to specify port 30001.
The port 30001 for app1 and 30002 for app2 is chosen because I specify these in the cluster yaml since I use kind:
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
    extraPortMappings:
      - containerPort: 30002
        hostPort: 30002

The yaml is the exact same for app1 just with port 30001.
for both app1 and app2 I use a NodePort service. Here's for app2:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app2
  ports:
    - port: 6666
      targetPort: 8888
      nodePort: 30002

The yaml is the same for app1 but targetPort is 7777 and nodePort is 30001.
The ingress yaml for app1 is:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "app1.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1service
            port:
              number: 6666


What do app1.example.com and app2.example.com resolve to?
